# Change jQuery namespace of a 3rd party component

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

As we using an older jQuery version (1.4) along with a newer one (1.11), we have 2 different namespaces for them. 1.4 uses the standard $ and 1.11 uses jQuery1111.

Now I'm trying to implement the froala editor, which need to use the 1.11 version. I've changed the froala code to this to make that happen:

```
(function (a) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = function (b, c) {
        return void 0 === c && (c = "undefined" != typeof window ? require("jquery") : require("jquery")(b)), a(c), c
    } : a(jQuery)
}(function (a) {

...

}(window.jQuery1111)));
```

But this gives me the error `a is not a function` (but the script seems to be able to run). The error is caught on the 4th line in the script above.

If I change `a(jQuery)` on the 4th line to `jQuery1111` it runs with no errors, but Im not sure if thats correct or if it will result in a bug later on.

Is this the correct way of implementing a 3rd party component into a non default jQuery namespace?

**Update: Script Order**

Inside `<head />`

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery1111 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    window.jQuery1111 = window.jQuery1111 || jQuery1111;
</script>
```

Inside `<body />`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share the script include order...

Comment: @ArunPJohny Question updated with script order

Comment: just move the original `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/froala_editor.min.js"></script>` before calling `noConflict()` - ie soon after including `1.11.1`

Comment: The more poignant question is, why is it worth the effort to maintain two versions of jQuery on your site when it's easier to port the outdated codes to the modern spec?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dazmmbq4/1/

Comment: @Terry We are actually rewriting the whole application in another project and at the moment we just want to implement a new editor, so its not worth it to port the code for us.

Comment: @ArunPJohny that works! Put it in an answer and Ill mark it as corrcect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the order of script include to fix the issue without modifying the 3rd party libraries

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.1.0/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery1111 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  window.jQuery1111 = window.jQuery1111 || jQuery1111;
</script>
```